# Проитерировать два целых положительных числа так, чтобы их произведения составили невозрастающую последовательность

Tags: c, алгоритм

Добрый день! Могли бы вы подсказать алгоритм для следующей задачи:
Даны два целых положительных числа n,m.
Необходимо получить последовательность чисел i,j таких, что 
i<=n,j<=m

[image: e=mc^2]

и для каждых двух членов последовательности выполнено условие:

[image: e=mc^2]

Использовал код:

```
k=(subWidth-1)*subHeight;
l=subWidth*(subHeight-1);
m=(subWidth-1)
if (k>l )
    --subWidth;
else
    --subHeight;
```

Мое решение пропускает значения, например для n=5,m=6:

```
5x6=30
5x5=25
5x4=20
4x4=16
```

пропущено 3x6=18

Comment: Самый тупой вариант - перебрать все, отсортировав :)

Comment: Хранить значения не хочется, потому что n<=2000,m<=2000

Comment: а вообще думаю можно было бы уменьшать произведение, и печатать если удается разложить его на подходящие сомножители

Comment: прошу прощения, дал ссылку не на ту формулу. Исправил

Comment: 2000 на 2000 целых - это всего 16 мегабайт :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил просто создать массив всех уникальных значений произведений и отсортировать его quicksort. Задача решена

Comment: Условие из вопроса (<=) подразумевает, что значения произведений могут повторяться, а вы решили задачу только для уникальных.

Answer (score 0):

Простое в лоб `O(n*m*n)` решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned n = 5, m = 6;
  for (unsigned product = n*m; product; --product)
    for (unsigned i = n; i; --i)
      if (product % i == 0 && product / i <= m)
          printf("%u %u\n", i, product / i);
}
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/gc8H0T)

```
5 6
5 5
4 6
5 4
4 5
3 6
4 4
5 3
3 5
4 3
3 4
2 6
5 2
2 5
3 3
4 2
2 4
3 2
2 3
1 6
5 1
1 5
4 1
2 2
1 4
3 1
1 3
2 1
1 2
1 1
```